# Fixing typo in paper after acceptance

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, editors

Last week I received the pleasant message that my very first journal paper got accepted. More precisely, the journal "accepts the manuscript in its current form". The reviewers did have some remarks, however. I know that I do not have to correct some bigger discussion points that they have, but there were also a couple of typos that they pointed out

**Do I need to correct those typos myself or will the reviewer/editor fix those, given that the mistakes are recognized?**

*Note. The manuscript submission website does not allow me to make any more changes, since its acceptance. I would probably have to e-mail the editor to correct the minor mistakes.*

Comment: Ask the editor. Different journals have different policies, we cannot tell you how it works in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had your paper not been accepted as is, you would definitely have made these changes. Although typos are usually taken care of in the copyediting and page proofing stage, I think it would be a good idea to write to the editor asking whether you are required to make the changes.